# how to transform let expression to cps?

Tags: scheme, continuation-passing

I want to know how to transform a let expression to continuation passing style like this:

```
(let ([a (lambda (x) (+ 1 x))]) (a 4))
```

Please show me some examples.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the `let` is macro-expanded to the following:

```
((lambda (a)
   (a 4))
 (lambda (x)
   (+ 1 x)))
```

So, now, let's CPS-transform the above, and we get:

```
((lambda (a k)
   (a 4 k))
 (lambda (x k)
   (+ 1 x k))
 k)
```

where the `k` on the final line is the continuation your original `let` uses.

If all those `k`s look too confusing, here's the same code:

```
((lambda (a k1)
   (a 4 k1))
 (lambda (x k2)
   (+ 1 x k2))
 k0)
```

where the `k0` is the original continuation.

In both cases, I assume that `+` is also similarly CPS-transformed to take a continuation to pass the result of the addition to....